# Expectation of trigonometric functions involving random variables.

Tags: trigonometry, random-variables, approximation, expectation

This is more a formulation question. I need help making a sales pitch (lol). I am working on an practical engineering problem where I encounter functions of the form:

$\cos(\phi + d_\phi)$, $  \tan(\phi+d_{\phi}) $ etc.

where $\phi$ is a deterministic variable taking values to the open interval  $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ and $d_{\phi}$ is a zero mean random variable, possibly Gaussian, but not necessarily.

Under what assumptions, or how should I phrase/justify the following:

$E[\cos(\phi + d_{\phi})] \approx E[\cos(\phi)]$

$E[\tan(\phi + d_{\phi})] \approx E[\tan(\phi)]$

$E[\sec(\phi + d_{\phi})] \approx E[\sec(\phi)]$

where $E$ represents the expectation operator. I did plot the above using Matlab and qualitatively the above approximations look OK. I am looking for some form analytical justification.
Please feel free to make any assumptions in your response. For example, I started with the most obvious and conservative assumption on the noise magnitude:

$|d_{\phi}|<c$ where $c$ is some small positive constant.

Any other suggestion?
Much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

Use trig identities such as $\cos (A +B) = \cos A \cos B-\sin A\sin B$

Then, as they are independent: $\mathsf E(\cos (A +B)) = \mathsf E(\cos A)\mathsf E(\cos B)-\mathsf E(\sin A)\mathsf E(\sin B)$

Thus if $B$ is zero mean and *symmetrically* distributed, you have $\mathsf E(\sin B)= 0$ (as Sine is an odd function).

You must also show that for *your particular* distribution $\mathsf E(\cos B) \approx 1$ (which is not *generally* true).

Comment: The cos() case is  the simplest one. However, the expansion of tan() involves a rational function, and therefore adds another level of complexity to your suggestion. i.e. $\tan(a+b) = \frac{\tan a + \tan b}{1 - \tan a \tan b}$.  I think this could approach a NP hard problem, but I am curious what asp,tons would be sufficient such that the approximations hold.

Comment: The cos() case is  the simplest one. However, the expansion of tan() involves a rational function, and therefore adds another level of complexity to your suggestion. i.e. $\tan(a+b) = \frac{\tan a + \tan b}{1 - \tan a \tan b}$.  I know that the above are not true (hence the approximation).  I am curious what assumptions would be sufficient such that the approximations hold.